# Stackoverflow API - get "received" upvote count of a user

Tags: stackexchange-api

I'm currently using the Stackoverflow API to get a list of detailed user information (via http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/users-by-ids).
There is an attribute called "up_vote_count" which returns the number of how often a user has GIVEN upvotes. What I want is some kind of the opposite:

Is it possible with the Stackoverflow API to get/calculate the count of how often a user RECEIVE upvotes?

The only way I would see is to crawl through the reputation changes via http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/user-reputation-changes and add +1 to a local upvote variable if there is "+10 reputation". But this would suck pretty hard...

Any Ideas?

Comment: this question is off topic. belongs on http://stackapps.com/